# How can I configure environment variables on a Docker container without hard-coding them in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My dockerfile pulls a code repository from a private source which requires private credentials, and right now they are being hardcoded in the dockerfile as Environment variables. Is there a way to send them as either parameters like:
`docker run --name myContainer --env USER=user@email.com --env PASS=password sgarcia/myimage`

Is this possible?

---

edit: I'm an idiot, my pseudo code worked. I didn't think it was as simple as taht. Thanks Collin...

Comment: What you have there will work, you can use -e or --env on your docker run command.

Comment: holy crap...I was just typing pseudo code...

Comment: keep in mind that this is not secure, a `docker inspect`will show this (among other things)

Comment: I had no idea, what do you recommend @user2915097 as an alternative?

Comment: see Vault or Keywhiz  and look at http://container-solutions.com/docker-security-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the "pseudo-code" I came up to illustrate what I wanted actually worked for docker ...Thanks Collin

Comment: No problem, sign of a nice API really that you hit it.